# Automatically select related for OneToOne field

Tags: django-models, django-authentication, prefetch

In my Django project I have a Profile for each django User, and the Profile is related to an Info model.  Both relationships are OneToOne.  Since most of the time I am using both the Profile and the Info models for a user, I would like those to be selected by default so I don't hit the database again.  Is there any way to do this using Django authentication?

Answer (score 4):

I know this has been here for a while but I am adding my solution in case someone else faces a similar situation.
Django (as of v1.8 and even v1.7) allows you to **customized the managers** ( .objects used when querying )

You could have a manager like this for Profile:

```py
class ProfileManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(ProfileManager,self).get_queryset().select_related('user')
```

Then in the model:

```py
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        User,
        primary_key=True,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )

    # ... other fields 

    # the manager
    objects = ProfileManager()

    # ...
```

Then all your queries on **Profile** will automatically select the related user too.

*You could extend this code to include the **Info** model too.*

Answer (score 0):

Use django >=1.5 for custom User model use select related functionality.

```
user = User.objects.select_related('profile_related', 'info_related')
```