# Django: Automatically selecting related model UserProfile when retrieving User model

Tags: python, django, django-models

When showing `{{ user }}` in a Django template, the default behavior is to show the username, i.e. `user.username`.

I'm changing this to show the user's initials instead, which are stored in a separate (`OneToOneField`) `UserProfile` model.

So in `customsignup/models.py` I've overridden the `__unicode__` function successfully, with the desired result:

```
# __unicode__-function overridden.
def show_userprofile_initials(self):
    return self.userprofile.initials
User.__unicode__ = show_userprofile_initials
```

But of course, the database is hit again because it needs to independently select the `UserProfile` model every time a `user` object is asked to show itself as a string. So even though this works, it escalates the number of database hits quite a bit.

So what I'd like to do, is to automatically use `select_related('userprofile')` whenever a `User` model is called from the database, seeing that I will essentially always want the profile when dealing with the user in the first place.

In more technical terms, I'm attempting to override the model manager of an existing model. So I'm in no control over the `User` model definition itself, since that's in an imported library.

So I've tried overriding the `objects` member of the `User` model in the same way that I overrode the `__unicode__` function, like so:

```
# A model manager for automatically selecting the related userprofile-table
# when selecting from user-table.
class UserManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        # Testing indicates that code here will NOT run.
        return super(UserManager, self).get_queryset().select_related('userprofile')
User.objects = UserManager()
```

Is this supposed to work? If so, what am I getting wrong?

*(I will mark an answer as correct if it can show that this is not supposed to work in the first place.)*

A similar question I've found is here, but it's approached from the other end:
[Automatically select related for OneToOne field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19673608/automatically-select-related-for-onetoone-field)

Comment: Why not just `user.profile.initials`? Creating the OneToOne field on your profile model also creates a reverse accessor for instances of the related model. You can specify the reverse accessor name by the `related_name` keyword argument on the profile model field. e.g. `user = models.OneToOneField('auth.User', related_name='profile')`

Comment: I'd usually avoid foreign keys in `__str__`/`__unicode__` methods. If you *always* want to show the initials instead of the username, that's perhaps a sign that the initials should be a field on a custom `User` model. Even if you don't do this, it would be a good idea to create a custom user model if you are just starting your project. That way you can use your custom manager instead of trying to monkeypatch the default `User` model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `User.objects = MyManger()` is not supposed to work. [According to the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model), there are just two supported methods for extending the provided auth User model, either a *profile* model, as you are doing, or a *proxy* model, which probably doesn't fit your case. From the docs (emphasis added):

> There are two ways to extend the default User model without substituting your own model. If the changes you need are **purely behavioral, and don’t require any change to what is stored in the database**, you can create a **proxy model** based on User. This allows for any of the features offered by proxy models including default ordering, custom managers, or custom model methods.
>
> If you wish to store information related to User, you can use a OneToOneField to a model containing the fields for additional information. This one-to-one model is often called a **profile model**, as it might **store non-auth related information** about a site user.

As an alternative to extending the provided auth User model, you can [provide your own custom User model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model). Then you will have complete control over its managers.

Instead, consider simply replacing `{{ user }}` with `{{ user.profile.initials }}`. Creating the OneToOne field on your profile model also creates a reverse accessor for instances of the related model. You can specify the reverse accessor name by the related_name keyword argument on the profile model field. For example...

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserProfile(models.Model)
    user = models.OneToOneField('auth.User', related_name='profile')
    initials = models.CharField(max_length=6)

some_user = User.objects.first()
# assuming there is already a profile related to this user
some_user.profile.initials = 'S.P.Y.'
```

You could also make a `__str__` method for your profile model like

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.initials
```

Then when you do `{{ user.profile }}` in a template, the initials will be shown.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The only point of trying to do it in the manner I described in the question, was my ambition to change as little as possible and avoid mistakes when replacing instances of {{ user }}, especially with regard to performance optimization. But I accept the answer as correct, although it appears my ambition will not be realized this time. :) Your proposed solution is the path I expected to be necessary if my attempt were impossible anyway. Thanks again!